# Perl parsing the csv file

Tags: perl

I am just trying to read .csv file first time.I have gone through the below link :

http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#Reading-a-CSV-file-line-by-line:

I have few doubt, well if you want, u can tell me this are silly question but i don't know, why i am not able to figure it out that how exactly perl is reading csv file :(

So, my doubt is:

**First Question**

What is the difference between reading the csv file line by line and parsing the file.

I have simple program where i am reading  the csv file line by line.
Below is my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csv=Text::CSV->new( );
my $my_file="test.csv";
open(my $fl,"<",$my_file) or die"can not open the file $!";
#print "$ref_list\n";

while(my $ref_list=$csv->getline($fl))
{
 
print "$ref_list->[0]\n";
}
```

Below is the data in csv file  :

```
"Emp_id","Emp_name","Location","Company"
102713,"raj","Banglore","abc"
403891,"Rakesh","Pune","Infy"
530201,"Kiran","Hyd","TCS"
503110,"raj","Noida","HCL"
```

**Second Question:**

If I want to get  specific Emp_id along with Location then how can i proceed.

**Third Question :**

If I want only 102713 ,530201,503110 Emp record i.e name,location,compnay name then what should i do ?

Thanks

Comment: parsing the file = reading/interpreting the whole thing. line-by-line lets you stop anytime you want, because only a single line is processed at a time. As for your other questions - once the data's read/parsed by person, you can do whatever you want with the returned array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CSV file is a good representation of tabular data in a text format, but it is unsuitable for an in-memory represenation. Because of that, we have to create an adequate representation. One such representation would be a hash:

```
my $hashref = {
   Emp_Id   => ...,
   Emp_name => ...,
   Location => ...,
   Company  => ...,
};
```

If the header row is in the array `@header`, we can create this hash with:

```
my @header = ...;
my @row = @{$csv->getline($fl)}; # turn the arrayref into an array
my $hashref = {};
for my $i (0..$#header) {
  $hashref->{$header[$i]} = $row[$i];
}
# The $hashref now looks as described above
```

We can then create lookup hashes that use the id values as keys. So `%lookup` looks like this:

```
my %lookup = (
   102713 => $hashref_to_first_line,
   ...,
);
```

We populate it by doing

```
$lookup{$row[0]} = $hashref;
```

after the above loop. We can then access a certain hashref with

```
my $a_certain_id_hashref = $lookup{102713};
```

or access certain elements directly with

```
my $a_certain_id_location = $lookup{102713}{Location};
```

If the key does not exist, these lookups should return `undef`.

If the CSV file is too big, this might cause perl to run out of memory. In that case, the hashes should be `tie`d to files, but that is a different topic completely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that addresses your second question and part of your third question:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Text::CSV;

my @empID = qw/ 102713 530201 503110 /;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } )
  or die 'Cannot use CSV: ' . Text::CSV->error_diag();

my $my_file = "test.csv";
open my $fl, '<', $my_file or die "can not open the file $!";

while ( my $ref_list = $csv->getline($fl) ) {

    if ( $ref_list->[0] ~~ @empID ) {
        say "Emp_id: $ref_list->[0] is Location: $ref_list->[2]";
    }
}

$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fl;
```

Output:

```
Emp_id: 102713 is Location: Banglore
Emp_id: 530201 is Location: Hyd
Emp_id: 503110 is Location: Noida
```

The array `@empID` contains the ID(s) you're interested in.  In the `while` loop, each Emp_id is checked using the smart match operator (Perl v5.10+) to see if it's in the list of IDs.  If so, the Emp_id and its corresponding Location is printed.