# Extract data from csv with perl

Tags: perl, csv, extract, large-files

I have a massive csv file full of data, and I need to extract only the yes/no (1-16 part) preserving the comma and breaking to a new line once it has completed the loop

Here is a snapshot of the data

```
Firstname: xxx
Lastname: xxx
Email: xxx@xxx.net
Phone: xxxxxxxxxx
IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
xxxx,Suttle,OR,United States,xxxxxx@xxx.com,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxx xxxx,"UnkNo,wn",Long Form,New,23/xxxxx,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,4/17/2014 13:45,4/17/2014 13:45,S3S - Survival,xxxxxx.com,4/17/2014 0:00,4/17/2014 13:45,"  
1.  No,
2.   No,
3.  No,
4.  No,
5.  No,
6.  No,
7.  No,
8.  No,
9. No,
10.  No,
11.  No,
12. No,
13.  No,
14.  No,
15.  No,
16.  Yes,
```

I have tried extracting the yes/no data above using every method I can think of, and I still cant extract correctly!  Any suggestions, gladly appreciated

Desired output is in a CSV file looking like this
http://pastebin.com/LerQ9vE4

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? More information is needed to help solve the problem

Comment: I have tried parsing the data, searching with regex for "yes" or "no" and outputting to a new file

Comment: What I was meaning is to include the code that you have tried as let people provide better help and possibly spot an error or two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl parsing the csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345775/perl-parsing-the-csv-file)

Comment: something very similar to this
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $mydir = './test/';

opendir (DIR, $mydir) or die $!;

while(my $file = readdir(DIR)){
   if ($file =~ /^GetStatus\.(\d+)\.log$/){

      if ($1 >= 123456 || $1 < 345678){
           open(my $fh,'<', $mydir . $file) or die "Cannot open file $file: $!\n";
           while (<$fh>){
             if ($_ =~ /YourSearchPattern/){
                print $_;
            }
           }
           close($fh);
      }
   }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, "<", "csvfile"; 
open my $op, ">", "output.txt";

my $flag;

while(<$fh>) {
    if ($_ =~ /\d+\.\s*(\w+,)/) {
        print $op "\n" if ($flag eq "Y");
        $flag = "N";
        print $op "$1";
    } else {
        $flag = "Y";
    }
}
```

- Using a `while loop` read one line at a time.
- Test the current line against a regex which states:

  - Look for a line that starts with one or more digit `^\d+`
  - Followed by a literal dot `.`
  - Followed by zero of more spaces `\s*`.
  - Using a captured group for `(\w+,)` to capture any word followed by a `,`.
- Print the line if it matches the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
open my $fin, "your.file";
my $str;
for (<$fin>) {                # read line into $_ variable
  if (/^\s*\d+\.\s*(\w+)/) {  # extract word from $_
    $str .= $1 . ",";         # append word and comma to $str
  }
}
print $str;
```